# PostGIS distance query using a dynamic radius

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-index, st-dwithin

(Background: I'm more of a MySQL guy, I've only been using PostGIS for a few months to solve this particular problem set.)

I have a table that contains a point and a radius:

```
id      | location                                            | radius
1469989 | 0101000020E6100000091B9E5E292651C0DCF4673F529E5140  | 100
1948448 | 0101000020E6100000BB0A293F299863C03B8908FF22D35140  | 10
```

I want to do a search that basically says "get me all points within (20 km + radius) from me". In other words, some points need to "reach" farther than others and need to be returned from farther away, whereas others have a smaller radius.

My understanding is that I can't use spatial indexes for this since the DB doesn't know in advance what that radius will be.

My other option is to use ST_Buffer to create a buffer with the radius. But this seems to be pretty slow since there are hundreds of thousands of points, each of which get turned into a polygon with X points (default is 36). This is powering a real-time feature, so it needs to be really fast.

Any tips on what the best way to do this is? Or is this just not going to work and I need to look into more aggressive caching / in-memory stores?

**Update**

The current index looks like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "places_location" ON "places" USING gist("location");
```

and here's a sample query (20 is a dynamic value that IRL would be parameterized):

```
explain analyze SELECT id from places
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint('-79.387', '43.642')::geography, places.location, 20 *radius*1000);
```

Results:

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..7076917.51 rows=68 width=8) (actual time=387.909..5444.545 rows=458668 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on places  (cost=0.00..7075910.71 rows=28 width=8) (actual time=1017.367..5100.683 rows=152889 loops=3)
"        Filter: st_dwithin('0101000020E610000054E3A59BC4D853C01904560E2DD24540'::geography, location, (('20'::double precision * radius) * '1000'::double precision), true)"
        Rows Removed by Filter: 72442
Planning Time: 0.886 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 12
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 29.416 ms, Inlining 593.395 ms, Optimization 1217.528 ms, Emission 941.965 ms, Total 2782.304 ms"
Execution Time: 5598.359 ms
```

This is what it looks like without dynamic radius:

```
explain analyze SELECT id from places
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint('-79.387', '43.642')::geography, places.location, 20*1000);
```

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on places  (cost=19.15..10423.16 rows=68 width=8) (actual time=38.297..242.233 rows=8849 loops=1)
"  Filter: st_dwithin('0101000020E610000054E3A59BC4D853C01904560E2DD24540'::geography, location, '20000'::double precision, true)"
  Rows Removed by Filter: 2958
  Heap Blocks: exact=6553
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on places_location  (cost=0.00..19.13 rows=363 width=0) (actual time=31.454..31.456 rows=11807 loops=1)
"        Index Cond: (location && _st_expand('0101000020E610000054E3A59BC4D853C01904560E2DD24540'::geography, '20000'::double precision))"
Planning Time: 8.443 ms
Execution Time: 247.098 ms
```

Comment: Instead of using a buffer you could represent the points using an enlarged bounding box via `ST_Expand`.  Also, you might be able to use a functional index to avoid storing the boxes in the table itself.

Comment: Is the main difference between ST_Buffer and ST_Expand that ST_Expand around a point basically ends up being a square rather than a jagged circle?

Comment: Functional index is an interesting idea, I can try that out too!

Answer (score 5):

It seems like an odd detail of the engine that an *ad-hoc* lookup with varying filter parameters is not sargable - *technically*, the index wouldn't care. But an RDBS is a system with persisted data in mind, and this limitation is required to support functionality, and boost performance, elsewhere.

That being said, what you really need in order to gain access to index lookups is to *persist* those varying radii into known and types and sargable arguments - and about the only suitable way in this scenario would be to use a *functional index* on the expanded `POINT` geometries:

```
-- for GEOMETRY; note the implications of CRS and their units for <radius>!!!
CREATE INDEX ON <table> USING GIST ( ST_Expand(location, radius + <extra>) );

-- for GEOGRAPHY; unit of <radius> is meter!!!
CREATE INDEX ON <table> USING GIST ( _ST_Expand(location, radius + <extra>) );
```

and

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  <table> AS t
WHERE
  -- either for GEOMETRY or GEOGRAPHY; note that the expression needs to match that of the index definition EXACTLY
  [_]ST_Expand(t.geom, t.radius + <extra>) && <INPUT_POINT>
  AND
  ST_DWithin(
    <INPUT_POINT>,
    t.geom,
    t.radius + <extra>
  )
;
```

*It seems equally odd that, given the functional index is in place, `ST_DWithin` cannot use it by itself even though internally it used to do the exact same index invocation.*

**Update:**

If you need `extra` to be dynamic at query time, but essentially static per query, you'd simply want to change the above to this:

```
-- for GEOMETRY; note the implications of CRS and their units for <radius>!!!
CREATE INDEX ON <table> USING GIST ( ST_Expand(location, radius) );

-- for GEOGRAPHY; unit of <radius> is meter!!!
CREATE INDEX ON <table> USING GIST ( _ST_Expand(location, radius) );
```

and

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  <table> AS t
WHERE
  -- either for GEOMETRY or GEOGRAPHY; note that the expression needs to match that of the index definition EXACTLY
  [_]ST_Expand(t.geom, t.radius) && [_]ST_Expand(<INPUT_POINT>, <extra>)
  AND
  ST_DWithin(
    <INPUT_POINT>,
    t.geom,
    t.radius + <extra>
  )
;
```

---

**However:**

Point to point distance is *cheap*. Always, even for spherical/spheroidal calculations. Index lookups are only cheap *in relation*, e.g. when their initial load up and random row access penalty are neglectable compared to their impact on e.g. large Cartesian joins. Their efficiency degenerates fast with increasing matches.

With that in mind, for a single input `POINT` against a few million stored `POINT`s it will likely be faster to see 2 or more parallel worker nodes spun up and do sequential scans for higher match counts!

Comment: Unfortunately the `extra` might be dynamic, i.e. it is an input to the query. Does that mean a functional index won't work?

I know that point-to-point *should* be cheap, which is why I was so confused as to why a simple `ST_Distance` was taking so long. :( This needs to be really fast (sub-100ms if possible) - hence my question whether this can even be done successfully in Postgis.

Comment: @DanielOrner so the parametric `extra` will be static per query?

Comment: @DanielOrner see my update.

Comment: You don't need ST_Expand.  That is already encoded in ST_DWithin. Also your index should just be against the geography, not any _ST_Expand nonsense.  That is not needed.

Comment: @ReginaObe `ST_DWithin` (or `&&` for that matter) ***cannot*** use any index *if the distance condition is dynamic*! The query in your answer does *not* use the index on `geom|geog`!

Comment: @ReginaObe and I believe that is true even with the newer `SUPPORT` functionality (compared to the old pre-issued `&&` index invocation inside the function) - see https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/f36874a448e9256aa231e01d44334c1278ebf7a6/postgis/gserialized_supportfn.c#L469

Comment: @ReginaObe ...and I just tested on PostGIS 3.2 (having the `SUPPORT` functionality) and `POINT` tables with sizes between 10^5 and 10^8 - exact setup and requirements as in OPs question, proper indexation, vacuumed - *without any index usage for plain `ST_DWithin`*, **but** fully index powered with my `[_]ST_Expand` setup.

Comment: @ReginaObe same even with `ENABLE_SEQSCAN = off;`

Comment: Thanks so much for your time looking into this - I'll definitely give this a shot!

Comment: @geozelot agree you do need _ST_Expand in this case for the pois index to be used. I  was too focussed on the common case where pois table is small relative to the population of points you are matching against, so the  pop.geog && _ST_Expand(poi.geog, radius + dynamic)  would trigger use of the pop.geog index, and your poi table would be on the one side would be held constant

Answer (score 4):

If the radius values are fairly similar, select first using the greatest radius (always, as a constant, so the index can be used) and refine the results using the variable width radius

```sql
...
where a.geom && st_expand(g.geom,25000) 
and st_dwithin(a.geom,b.geom, a.radius)
```

Comment: Hmm... wondering if this would help since this would have thousands or tens of thousands of extra hits on the index that would have to be shaved down. I can experiment.

Answer (score 2):

- First is your data stored as geography type or geometry type.  I would suggest changing it to geography especially if you are a newbie.  Otherwise you'd need to understand spatial reference systems, which is another topic altogether.
- I'm also assuming your radius is stored in kilometers thus the need to multiply by 1000, since geography always measures in meters
- Make sure your points are in order of longitude,latitude  **NOT** longitude,latitude, which is a common mistake of people especially mappers (since many mapping platforms expect latitude,longitude)

Here are some self contained examples using your example points

```
    CREATE TABLE pois(id integer, geog geography(POINT,4326), radius float8, CONSTRAINT pk_pois PRIMARY KEY(id));
    
    INSERT INTO pois(id, geog, radius)
    VALUES (1469989,'0101000020E6100000091B9E5E292651C0DCF4673F529E5140'::geography(POINT,4326), 100 ), 
    (1948448,'0101000020E6100000BB0A293F299863C03B8908FF22D35140'::geography(POINT,4326), 10 );
    
    CREATE INDEX ix_pois_geog ON pois USING gist(geog);
    
    -- checking a table of points
    SELECT p.*, pois.id
    FROM points_to_check AS p INNER JOIN pois ON ST_DWithin(pois.geog, pop.geog, pois.radius*1000 + 20*1000);
    
    -- checking a single point NOTE: coordinates are longitude,latitude
    SELECT pois.*
    FROM pois 
    WHERE ST_DWithin(pois.geog, ST_Point(70.10,-68)::geography(POINT,4326), pois.radius*1000 + 20*1000);
```

Comment: um... yes, it's geography, but I'm not sure how this answers the question?

Comment: Your radiuses are kept in the table, correct?  I'm assuming, you are either checking one point at a time or you have a table of points (points_to_check) you want to check against your table of point dynamic radius and determine which ones satisfy the within condition

Comment: Also your assumption that PostGIS can't use an index on your point cause your radius is not constant is mistaken.  If you are seeing your index not being used, it's probably for another reason.  I'm on the PostGIS Dev team BTW and wrote a book on this https://manning.com/obe3 so I know how ST_DWIthin works and how it leverages indexes.

Comment: To alleviate any doubt, would you mind adding the `explain` plan of the query with dynamic distances and that still use the spatial index?

Comment: I understand what you are saying now. In this case if you have say a large points_to_check table relative to your pois table, the planner will hold the pois table constant and not use the index anyway regardless if you have one.
 Usually the case is that your pois with distance row set is small relative to the population you are comparing against so you want the index on the points_to_check to be used, but if your pois is much larger than the table of points you are checking, then @geozelot's solution is the best answer